# Trying to run a function on Ender Dragon death

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm somewhat new to coding, I'm trying to have the Ender Dragon load an mcstructure on death.
You can see my current code attempt below; any thoughts on how to make this work?

```
    "format_version": "1.10.0",
    "animation_controllers": {
        "controller.animation.death": {
        "initial_state":"default",
            "states": {
                "default": {
                    "transitions": [
                        {
                            "dead": "ender_dragon.q.is_alive"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "dead": {
                    "on_entry": ["/structure load dragon_drops ~ ~ ~"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```